# JavaScript: forma de contar os caracteres de um texto html?

Tags: javascript, html, string, xml

O problema: eu tenho um texto html formatado e preciso contar quantos caracteres (toques para os jornalistas) eu tenho. Vou usar JavaScript. Algumas soluções me vieram à mente, mas como isso será feito de forma repetitiva, resolvi analisar melhor antes de sair codificando:

1. O mais obvio: remover as tags. Preciso localizá-las, e criar uma nova string sem elas. Me parece a mais lenta e, se o texto for grande, pode requerer alguma memória.
2. Percorrer a string: paro a contagem toda a vez que uma tag é aberta, e reinicio quando é fechada. Me atrai pela simplicidade, mas um tanto primitiva, talvez fique lenta em strings grandes.
3. Transformar num XML e percorrer somando os comprimento dos nós de texto. Não tenho muita prática, mas parece interessante porque usará o "core" do JavaScript, talvez fique mais rápido e otimize a utilização da memória em função disso.

Alguém já fez algo parecido? Qual a melhor "aproximação" do problema?

Comment: Pode usar jQuery ou só javascript puro? Poderia mostrar um exemplo desse texto formatado?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solução é muito mais simples do que você está pensando. Você não precisa eliminar as tags, basta pegar somente o texto delas com a propriedade [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```js
var elemento = document.querySelector('div');
// compatibilidade com IE antigo via innerText
var conteudo = elemento.textContent || elemento.innerText; 
alert(conteudo.length); // 1
```

```html
<div><span>a</span></div>
```

Comment: +1 pela simplicidade.

Comment: Caramba! Não sabia que existia esse metodozinho milagroso! Valeu!